# Convert combobox string value to int

Tags: c#, parsing, combobox

I have a question about converting types. I want to change the currently selected combobox value string to an int, but I get errors

My code:

```
int.Parse(age.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

What can I do for this problem?

Comment: See the tags. Yes, C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok now we know the error, you can check for a null value before trying to parse it using:

```
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        int x = int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
    else { //Value is null }
```

You can avoid a null value being passed by setting the text property of the control to what ever default value you want.

If you are still not getting a value after making sure one is selected you really need to post your code.

Comment: all of them are numbers but the error is like that 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: on what? the age.SelectedItem? Post the relevant code and I will have a look.

What your error is saying is that nothing is selected in the combo box; check you have selected a value in the combo box

Comment: what can I do for this problem I get same error with the codes you have written

Comment: Thank you very much the problem is solved I tried and to see that it works I made addition ,it worked

Comment: No problem :) glad we sorted it

Comment: @Yoda He never answered me -- is this C# after all? I'd like to tag the question properly, but I don't know the language so I'm not sure, it just looked kind of like it

Comment: Yes it is, sorry didnt see your comment last night

Answer (score 1):

`TryParse` is a good method for this sort of thing:

```
int value;
if (!Int32.TryParse(this.comboBoxNumeric.Text, out value))
{
    //Do something fun...
}
```

Comment: I prefer the TryParse method because it is much quicker for errors versus throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Convert.ToInt32 method. You can always use the databinding like this:

---

```
class A
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

cbo.DataSource = new A[]{new A{ID=1, Name="hello"}};
cbo.DisplayMember = "Name";
cbo.DisplayValue = "ID";

int id = Convert.ToInt32(cbo.SelectedValue);
A a = (A) cbo.SelectedItem;
int a_id = a.ID;
int a_name = a.Name;
```

---

If you use [LINQ to DataSets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_DataSets), develop is very easy for C# program.

Answer (score 0):

```
        try
        {
            string name = comboBoxPort.SelectedItem.ToString();
            int portBaudrate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxBaudrate.SelectedItem);
        }
```

//just solved
//enjoy

Comment: I don't think you'll need to declare a `name` variable if you're not going to use it. If it does, please explain why.